# Django OAuthToolkit Scopes per specific method

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, oauth2-toolkit

I'm using Django Rest Framework and [OAuthTookit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit).

I want that the scope provided by the token should be HTTP Method specific. For eg:- GET, PUT, DELETE of the same APIView should have different scopes.

Following are my APIs.

```
class MyView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [TokenHasScope]
    required_scopes = ['scope1']
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
```

Currently, the scope is set at the class level, which means to access all the GET, PUT & DELETE method, the token should have `scope1`.

I want that there should be different scope for different HTTP methods. How can I set different scope for different methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle this case, I think you need to implement a new permission class, something like this:

```
class TokenHasScopeForMethod(TokenHasScope):

     def has_permission(self, request, view):
         token = request.auth

         if not token:
             return False

         if hasattr(token, "scope"):
             # Get the scopes required for the current method from the view
             required_scopes = view.required_scopes_per_method[request.method]

             return token.is_valid(required_scopes)
```

And use it in your view like this:

```
class MyView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
     permission_classes = [TokenHasScopeForMethod]
     required_scopes_per_method = {'POST': ['post_scope'], 'GET': ['get_scope']}
     serializer_class = ModelSerializer
     queryset = Model.objects.all()
```

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm. (y)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps You can use [`TokenMatchesOASRequirements`](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/permissions.html#tokenmatchesoasrequirements) permission class

```
class SongView(views.APIView):
    authentication_classes = [OAuth2Authentication]
    permission_classes = [TokenMatchesOASRequirements]
    required_alternate_scopes = {
        "GET": [["read"]],
        "POST": [["create"], ["post", "widget"]],
        "PUT":  [["update"], ["put", "widget"]],
        "DELETE": [["delete"], ["scope2", "scope3"]],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @clément-denoix answer, but would tweak it a bit.

Instead of reloading `TokenHasScope.has_permission` I would suggest to redefine
`TokenHasScope.get_scopes` as it is smaller method and perfectly fit for what you need. Also original `has_permission` method has additional logic that I prefer to preserve.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import TokenHasScope


class TokenHasScopeForMethod(TokenHasScope):
    def get_scopes(self, request, view):

        try:
            scopes = getattr(view, "required_scopes_per_method")
            return scopes[request.method]
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "TokenHasScope requires the view to define the required_scopes_per_method attribute"
            )
```